# What does something like 'ウオエエエエエ' express?

Tags: sound-symbolism

The context is that the character was in the middle of a long winded speech about something, then noticed their friends weren't paying attention, and got a super annoyed looked on their face, like [this](http://tn.smilevideo.jp/smile?i=30363571.L), before making the sound. Anyone know? Because Google and my usual sources turned up extremely little

Comment: ↓　そのツイートの中のマンガの、https://twitter.com/WakyaOT34/status/934772444056895488「ごめんなさい…話を聞いてたら急に気分が悪くなって…ハ～ハ～　ウオエエエエ」っていうところは、「オエエ～」ってゲロを吐いている（=[嘔吐]{おうと}している）音です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating @Chocolate 's comment, I believe she's saying **it expresses the sound of one vomiting**.